android native - How my native library path not listed in GetMemoryRegions result when I debug using lldb?
I want to debug my native library libtestnative.so at the low level using lldb. In order to do that I have to know what is the base address of the target shared object. I wrote a lldb script leveraging the python framework to dump all memory regions but in the result list there was no entry of it though the code still executed normally.
I tried 2 things:

put a endless loop to keep the shared object "alive" in the process memory when I interrupted the process in lldb client:

jobject myNativeMethod3(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject arrayObj) {
    LOGI("Reading string array");

    struct timespec ts = {2, 0}; // 2 second sleep
    while(true){
        LOGI("waiting for lldb");
        nanosleep(&ts, nullptr);
    }
}


dump every entry to a file:

def get_memory_regions(debugger, command, result, internal_dict):
    target = debugger.GetSelectedTarget()
    process = target.GetProcess()
    if not process:
        print("No process available.")
        return

    region_list = process.GetMemoryRegions()
    print(f"Total regions: {region_list.GetSize()}")
    with open('regions.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(region_list.GetSize()):
            region_info = lldb.SBMemoryRegionInfo()
            if region_list.GetMemoryRegionAtIndex(i, region_info):
                name = region_info.GetName()
                f.write(f"{name}\n")

but the target shared object name not appeared in the list.
I could see there was an entry named /data/app/~~v4slxMbRQy4YqeFeTO3Rig==/com.example.testnative-Lkf80ctXP4dWS-iV201AwQ==/base.apk appeared, but I also expect a lib named libtestnative.so in the list.

What does your AndroidManifest.xml have for the extractNativeLibs attribute? If its not set or false, Android can map the library directly out of the apk. In which case your library offset is base address of that region plus the offset within the apk.
